# how propper get product id if is product - Elementor

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, elementor

we have custom plugin for manipulating product with Elementor controls, problem is in visual page editor when editing text, ajax error 500 is appearing and under that:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_id() on null ...for example:

```
protected function render()
{

     global $product;


    if (!is_product() && !is_object($product)) {
        return;
    }

   
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
}
```

If I remove this id problem is also in the gallery template where is also id and again in price.php where is also id.

What is your approach to get product data/id without those error

Comment: The context is quite unclear here, but won't a `if(!$product)` do?

Comment: @CBroe if I return if(!$product) when starting editing this content widget is empty ..not recognizing product anymore when triggering ajax ..and I'm still on product